# How Remove Border around a DatagridTextCell that appears on VerticalAlignment = Center?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I want to display datevalues in a `DataGrid`, whereas the text is vertically aligned in the center of the row, and not at the top. If I change the `VerticalAlignment` property in the `DataGridCell` Style, the text is aligned correctly, but a frame appears. Setting `BorderThickness` to 0 does not fix this.

How can I get rid of the frame/border and also display the text in the middle of the row?

`DataGrid` Style

```
<Style x:Key="StandardTabelle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="#ebecec"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="RowHeight" Value="24"/>
    <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{StaticResource StandardSpaltenKopf}" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserResizeRows" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserResizeColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="RowStyle" Value="{StaticResource AusgewählteZeile}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
```

Style for selected Row

```
<Style x:Key="AusgewählteZeile" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Rot}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Style for Datecell with top alignment

```
<Style x:Key="DatumZelle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />                
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom `ControlTemplate`:

```
<Style x:Key="DatumZelle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```